# How to redirect user request from http to https in liferay 6.2?

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, https, liferay-6

Tried with lot of configuration provided as answers but not working. Following one is very common solution at lot of answers.

To enable SSL open **apache-tomcat-7.0.62\conf\server.xml file** and uncomment following line:

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150"
minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
keystoreFile="/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/conf/SSLcertificate.cert"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

**apache-tomcat-7.0.62\conf\web.xml file**

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Do you have an Apache HTTP server in front (and you should!).  Handle that in there, not in Tomcat and-or Liferay.  Apache handles the http->https and ssl negotiation, talks to Tomcat in AJP behind.

Comment: The way you ask the question is not at all programming related, thus not a good fit for stackoverflow

Comment: @OlafKock I can see lot of questions like this on Stackoverflow with answers and comments, So I thought it would help me too.

Comment: @Nic3500 I don't have Apache HTTP server in front of Liferay, but if it can solve my problem, then some link will be appreciated!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic lists the on-topic questions here. You might also want to check out the Liferay forums, which have a broader focus (but please don't crosspost, or in this case, link your crossposts in both directions)